# Php database not able to be retrieved

Tags: php, mysqli

**I have a problem of data not being retrieved from database. It only echos the sentence that I typed instead of the data in my database. I've tried it for several times and it still does not work. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please help**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>database connections</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
      $username = "database-username";
      $password = "database-password";
      $host = "localhost";

      $connector = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password)
          or die("Unable to connect");
        echo "Connections are made successfully::";
      $selected = mysqli_select_db($connector, "test_db")
        or die("Unable to connect");

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table_one ");
      ?>
      <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee_id</th>
          <th>Employee_Name</th>
          <th>Employee_dob</th>
          <th>Employee_Adress</th>
          <th>Employee_dept</th>
          <td>Employee_salary</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
            echo
            "<tr>
              <td>{$row\['employee_id'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['employee_name'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['employee_dob'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['employee_addr'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['employee_dept'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['employee_sal'\]}</td> 
            </tr>\n";
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
     <?php mysqli_close($connector); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove the slashes from your brackets.

Comment: Do you mean like this?
            "<tr>
              <td>{$row['employee_id']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_name']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_dob']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_addr']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_dept']}</td>
              <td>{$row['employee_sal']}</td> 
            </tr>\n";

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I'm sorry but it still does not display the data from my database. For expample, it only displays this {$row['employee_id']} and not the data

Comment: If you view the source of the page, does it show you all of the mysqli code as well?

Comment: No, it dislays my desired table but instead of retrieving the data, it displays {$row['employee_id']} in the place where data from database should be appeared

Answer (score 0):

You need below Changes in your Code :

1) Change these line :

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table_one ");
```

**To below line :**

```
$result = mysqli_query($connector, "SELECT * FROM table_one ");
```

2) Change these lines :

```
          <td>{$row\['employee_id'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['employee_name'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['employee_dob'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['employee_addr'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['employee_dept'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['employee_sal'\]}</td>
```

**To Below Lines :**

```
          <td>{$row['employee_id']}</td>
          <td>{$row['employee_name']}</td>
          <td>{$row['employee_dob']}</td>
          <td>{$row['employee_addr']}</td>
          <td>{$row['employee_dept']}</td>
          <td>{$row['employee_sal']}</td>
```

That's It.